# Map a column multiple times

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a rather odd requirement in my fluent hibernate maps.  I have an table(A) which has a compound foreign key relationship with another table(B).  In the mapping for table A I would like to have both the object created from table B and access to the individual attributes of A which define the key. Is there any way to do that? I seem to get index out of range exceptions if I map the column twice.

I cannot just explore B for the attributes because the row in table B may not exist. I am painfully aware that there are some significant smells in the structure with which I'm dealing. Such is the fate of those who deal with legacy systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *kinda* possible, by hacking around a little.

We're going to define a domain that with a fake collection that we'll use to retrieve the single related element, if found:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual BarKey BarKey { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get { return Bars.SingleOrDefault(); } }
    protected virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual BarKey Id { get; set; }
}

//this class must override Equals and GetHashcode. Implementation not shown.
public class BarKey
{
    public virtual int X { get; set; }
    public virtual int Y { get; set; }
}
```

The `BarKey` component contains the properties that are part of the key.

Now, the mapping:

```
<class name="Foo">
  <id ...><generator .../></id>
  <component name="BarKey">
    <property name="X" />
    <property name="Y" />
  </component>
  <bag name="Bars" inverse="true">
    <key property-ref="BarKey">
      <column name="X"/>
      <column name="Y"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Bar">
  <composite-id name="Id">
    <key-property name="X" />
    <key-property name="Y" />
  </composite-id>
</class>
```

The `property-ref` attribute there tells NH to match those columns in Bar against the `BarKey` property of Foo instead of its Id.